# Why won't the textinputlayout in my xml show up?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-textinputlayout

The textinputlayout I created is for a login screen, but whenever the activity is launched, everything else shows except for that. Clicking on the space where it should be also does nothing (the keyboard does not come up) so it seems like its visibility has been set to "gone" even though it has not.

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="org.thelatinschool.canvasgrades.SplashScreenActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loadingProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ProgressBarStyle"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/afterAnimationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WelcomeTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Highlands Latin School"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/readItTogetherTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/WelcomeTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Canvas Grades"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/readItTogetherTextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:boxStrokeColor="#000000" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Forgot Password?"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/skipTextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/skipTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Incorrect username or password!"
        android:textColor="#B53737"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the corresponding java:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public String theme1;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private boolean animationStarted = false;
private ImageView bookIconImageView;
private TextView bookITextView;
private ProgressBar loadingProgressBar;
int progress;
private RelativeLayout rootView, afterAnimationView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);
    bookIconImageView = findViewById(R.id.logo);
    loadingProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.loadingProgressBar);
    rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);
    afterAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.afterAnimationView);
    Thread thred = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doWork();
            startApp();
        }
        public void doWork() {
            for (progress=10;progress<100;progress=progress+10){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(350);
                    loadingProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }} }
        public void startApp(){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                                  rootView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(SplashScreenActivity.this, R.color.splashscreen));
                                  bookIconImageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
                              }
                          });
            startAnimation();
        };
});
    thred.start();
}


private void startAnimation() {
    ViewPropertyAnimator viewPropertyAnimator = bookIconImageView.animate();
    viewPropertyAnimator.x(50f);
    viewPropertyAnimator.y(100f);
    viewPropertyAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    viewPropertyAnimator.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            afterAnimationView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
}
// Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
//        SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

I have an animation for the splash screen that displays right before the login screen, I haven't touched anything to do with the text input box in java but maybe I made a mistake somewhere there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you miss adding app level material design dependency

```
// material Design support library - androidx
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'


// material Design support library - support library
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

> UPDATE

You're missing adding `TextInputEditText` within `TextInputLayout`, so you won't expect to see something, also move `android:hint`, `android:textSize`, `android:textColorHint` & `android:textColor` attributes into  `TextInputEditText` instead of `TextInputLayout`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="outline">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I had the androidx support library already, but I still have the same issue

Comment: Yep that did it, and I didn't need the TextInputLayout just the EditText field

Comment: TextInputLayout is useful as well it shows you a little text above the TextInputEditText which has a better user experience while they are typing text in TextInputEditText for ex it shows the hint 'name' when the user typing their name

Comment: You **can't** use together the material components library and the support design

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti you're right, just put both as the question has no clue which one is used .. thanks